# You need at least 8.6GB storage space to install Ubuntu. This computer only has 8.6GB. What do I do - no other threads have helped

Tags: virtualbox

Here's what I've done:

- Installed ubuntu iso file
- Opened virtual box
- In system clicked 'Install Ubuntu'
- Then I get the error.

**I don't know what to do - I've looked at multiple other threads around this and none have helped!**

Thanks.

---

Here's my virtual disk.

ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

---

[Disk Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxA36.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide information about the virtual disk you are using.

Comment: Thanks. I've done that.

Comment: The info needed is the size, partitions, eTc. The file name provides no useful information. Also, that is not your virtual disk, it is the install image.

Comment: Ok, I think i've done that.

Comment: Now look at the virtual size amd compare that to the error message. The problem should be obvious. Make the virtual disk bigger.